# What other attributes do Facebook share/like button have?

Tags: facebook

I found some tutorial about adding FB share button on a web page, for example:

`<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.mypage.com/" data-type="button_count"></div>`

I guess there must be some more attributes like `data-type` for me to customize the button or the content. Is there any reference for this?

I expect to see a full list, or a link to the official page.

Thanks,

Comment: I thinkFacebook is trying to retire the share button and force you to use the like button. All the documentation is on like with share being just a check box. They also updated how their buttons work recently which just confused and annoyed me.

Comment: @Muskie Is there any solid (permanent) URL that I can rely on?

Comment: Official documentation talks about the recent changes. They tried to phase out the Share button but many like it. Some prefer "recommend" thinking it is more professional. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/